# Android circle ring inside text show the progress

Tags: android, android-view

i want to make below view , what  is the good way to make the below view.where highlighted area of the Ring shows the progress of some tasks. any help?

[image: custom view show progress]

Comment: Hey did you get the solution to this? I am on fire for this.

Comment: yes.for this it is best to make a custom view.

Comment: can you please share some code...?

Comment: please find the link http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/android-custom-circle-view-with-stroke/